# How to set parent on taxonomy term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have done:

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => 'title', 
  'vid' => 'myvocab',
])->save();
```

It works.

But I don't seem to be able to set the parent term.

I have tried:

```
$term->parent = array($parent_tid);
$term->save();
```

It gives an error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Value is not a valid entity. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference->setValue() (line 106 of /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Plugin/DataType/EntityReference.php).

I have also tried:

```
$term->parents = array($parent_tid);
$term->save();
```

It gives no error, but also does nothing.

In my code $term could be a new term or an existing term I've loaded, which is why I set the parent and then save it. But I can't get it to work.

Documentation for D8 is sparse. I've dug around the code in the taxonomy module, and it looks like `parent` is an entity reference field that accepts multiple values, but I can't work out how to set it. It looks like setting `parent` to array($id) should work, but I think the magic setter is breaking. Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct way for a reference field is to set the property target_id:

```
$term->parent = ['target_id' => '2'];
```

All this shorter versions work too:

```
$term->parent = ['2'];
$term->parent = '2';
$term->parent = 2;
```

Also works like this:

```
$term->set('parent', ['target_id' => 2]);
$term->set('parent', 2);
```

Comment: If you like using the get/set methods another valid format would be $term->set('parent', ['target_id' => 2]);

Comment: This may have changed as of 8.6.1... there was a standardization of the term parent field.

Comment: 8.9.1 `$term->parent = ['target_id' => $parent_id];` somehow didn't work whereas `$term->set('parent', ['target_id' => $parent_id]);` worked.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was doing it right after all: `$term->parent = array($parent_tid)`. The problem was that to find `$parent_tid`, I was using `$another_term->tid`. It turns out that this is a FieldItemList, and to get the tid I have to use `$another_term->tid->value`. I don't know if maybe there is a better way?

Comment: For all entities it is id(), you don't need to look it up in the field: `$term->id()`

Comment: The docs for Term class on the docs website do show all methods, and id() is one of them.